# WPF installation under Microsoft folder by default

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-installer

When I publish a WPF application from visual studio, it creates it under Microsoft folder in start menu of windows. How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, "Microsoft" is just the "Company name" you entered (looks like skipped entering) while installing Visual Studio. So every project by default has Company name as "Microsoft" in version info.

Either reinstall Visual Studio with your Company name, or change `Assembly info - Company` in every new project you create. That's what you see when you right-click EXE file, and go to `Properties->Details` tab.

Default options in `Properties > Publish > Options` should be taken from `Assembly info`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out its under Properties > Publish > Options, if you set Publisher name and product name correctly. It works.